# How to combine validation and navigation after single click

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, navigation

I want to validate my needed HTML inputs and deactivate them if they are empty, or allow the navigation button to call the next step and show parts with the id.

Right now validation and navigation run side by side and I get the error for empty input and forwarded to the next page too, where I go back to the last step to see the error, How can I stop navigation unless all required fields are filled?

my.js

```
function validateForm() {
  var form = document.getElementById("releaseForm");
  var elements = form.elements;

// Loop through all form elements
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
var element = elements[i];

// Check if the element is a required input field
if (element.hasAttribute("required") && element.value.trim() === "") {
  element.classList.remove("form-control");
  element.classList.add("error-border");
  
  // Find the associated label and add the error class
  var label = form.querySelector("label[for='" + element.id + "']");
  label.classList.add("error-label");
} else {
  element.classList.remove("error-border");
  element.classList.add("form-control");
  
  // Find the associated label and remove error class
  var label = form.querySelector("label[for='" + element.id + "']");
  label.classList.remove("error-label");
  
    }
   }
  }


   document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inputField) => {
     inputField.addEventListener("input", () => {
  // Remove the error styling when the user starts typing
    inputField.classList.remove("error-border");
   inputField.classList.add("form-control");

// Find the associated label and remove error class
var form = document.getElementById("releaseForm");
var label = form.querySelector("label[for='" + inputField.id + "']");
label.classList.remove("error-label");
 });
  });




  const navigateToFormStep = (stepNumber) => {
  /**
  * Hide all form steps.
  */
  document.querySelectorAll(".form-step").forEach((formStepElement) => {
  formStepElement.classList.add("d-none");
  });
  /**
  * Mark all form steps as unfinished.
  */
  document.querySelectorAll(".form-stepper-list").forEach((formStepHeader) => {
  formStepHeader.classList.add("form-stepper-unfinished");
  formStepHeader.classList.remove("form-stepper-active", "form-stepper-completed");
  });
  /**
  * Show the current form step (as passed to the function).
  */
  document.querySelector("#step-" + stepNumber).classList.remove("d-none");
  /**
  * Select the form step circle (progress bar).
  */
  const formStepCircle = document.querySelector('li[step="' + stepNumber + '"]');
  /**
  * Mark the current form step as active.
  */
  formStepCircle.classList.remove("form-stepper-unfinished", "form-stepper-completed");
  formStepCircle.classList.add("form-stepper-active");
  /**
  * Loop through each form step circles.
  * This loop will continue up to the current step number.
  * Example: If the current step is 3,
  * then the loop will perform operations for step 1 and 2.
  */
  for (let index = 0; index < stepNumber; index++) {
  /**
  * Select the form step circle (progress bar).
  */
  const formStepCircle = document.querySelector('li[step="' + index + '"]');
  /**
  * Check if the element exist. If yes, then proceed.
  */
  if (formStepCircle) {
  /**
   * Mark the form step as completed.
   */
  formStepCircle.classList.remove("form-stepper-unfinished", "form-stepper-active");
  formStepCircle.classList.add("form-stepper-completed");
  }
  }
  };
  /**
  * Select all form navigation buttons, and loop through them.
  */
  document.querySelectorAll(".btn-navigate-form-step").forEach((formNavigationBtn) => {
  /**
  * Add a click event listener to the button.
  */
  formNavigationBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  /**
  * Get the value of the step.
  */
  const stepNumber = parseInt(formNavigationBtn.getAttribute("step_number"));
  /**
  * Call the function to navigate to the target form step.
  */
  navigateToFormStep(stepNumber);
  });
  });
```

Here is my HTML

```
<form id="releaseForm">
  <section id="step-1" class="form-step">
  <div>Page 1</div>
  <input type="text" required value="">
  <button type="button" onclick="validateForm()" step_number="2">Next</button>
  </section>
  <section id="step-2" class="form-step">
  <div>Page 2</div>
  <button type="button" step_number="1">Prev</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="validateForm()" step_number="3">Next</button>
  </section>
  <section id="step-3" class="form-step">
  <div>Page 3</div>
  <button type="button" step_number="2">Prev</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="validateForm()">Save</button>
  </section>
</form>
```

My CSS to block/show elements and style errors and a circle progress steps

```
ul.form-stepper {
  counter-reset: section;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
  ul.form-stepper .form-stepper-circle {
  position: relative;
  }
  ul.form-stepper .form-stepper-circle span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  .form-stepper-horizontal {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
  ul.form-stepper > li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin-bottom 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin-bottom 0.4s;
  transition: margin-bottom 0.4s;
  }
  .form-stepper-horizontal > li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .form-stepper-horizontal li {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: start;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .form-stepper-horizontal li:not(:last-child):after {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  content: "";
  top: 32%;
  }
  .form-stepper-horizontal li:after {
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  }
  .form-stepper-horizontal li.form-stepper-completed:after {
  background-color: #4da3ff;
  }
  .form-stepper-horizontal li:last-child {
  flex: unset;
  }
  ul.form-stepper li a .form-stepper-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 0;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
  border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-active .form-stepper-circle {
  background-color: #4361ee !important;
  color: #fff;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-active .label {
  color: #4361ee !important;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-active .form-stepper-circle:hover {
  background-color: #4361ee !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-unfinished .form-stepper-circle {
  background-color: #f8f7ff;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-completed .form-stepper-circle {
  background-color: #0e9594 !important;
  color: #fff;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-completed .label {
  color: #0e9594 !important;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-completed .form-stepper-circle:hover {
  background-color: #0e9594 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-active span.text-muted {
  color: #fff !important;
  }
  .form-stepper .form-stepper-completed span.text-muted {
  color: #fff !important;
  }
  .error-border {
   display: block;
   color: #6e707e;
  }

 .error-label {
   color: red;
  }
```